# Using UIWebview+AFNetworking -loadRequest:progress:success:failure: breaks up web page design

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, afnetworking

I made a demo app with just a UITextField to enter URL and a UIWebview, trying to isolate the problem.

UIWebViewDelegate simply look like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  return YES;

}
```

And UITextFieldDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

     NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", textField.text]]];

//    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];

     [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

     } success:^NSString *(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSString *HTML) {

         return HTML;

     } failure:^(NSError *error) {

     }];

     [textField resignFirstResponder];

     return YES;

}
```

I'm wondering why when I try to load www.pornhub.com with default method it works perfectly but with the AFNetworking category, it loads a weird design.  Any idea of what's happening here?

Comment: Perhaps AFNetworking is making some kind of moral judgement.

Answer (score 1):

The requests are probably not equivalent. Less visible request information like `User-Agent`, `Accept`, or `Content-Type` headers, or cookies can have unforeseen effects when interacting with a web service.

You can see what request information is going over the wire by using an HTTP proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).